# Checkbox behavior is unusual Jquery

Tags: jquery

```js
function  SelectUnselect(){
    var boolCheckUncheck;
        debugger;
        if ($('.selectAll').prop('checked')) {
            boolCheckUncheck = true;
        }
        else boolCheckUncheck = false;

        $('.checkbox1:checkbox:visible').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('checked', boolCheckUncheck);
        });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"
  integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Select All</div>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="SelectUnselect()"  class="selectAll" />
<br/>
<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1"  />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />
</body>
</html>
```

I'm finding some unusual behavior in my web app.

Essentially I have three checkboxes

id= "1" - Select All

id= "2"

id= "3"

id=1 is Select All. So if user checks that in, then 2 and 3 get selected. Same with uncheck, both 2 and 3 get unselected. My code looks like this for the id=1 `onChange` event

```
 function SelectUnselect(){

    var boolVal;
    debugger;
    if ($('.selectAll').prop('checked')) {
        boolVal= true;
    }
    else boolVal= false;

    $('.theClass:checkbox:visible').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', boolVal);
    }); 
}
```

However, let's say I manually check in id=2, and then click on the SelectAll checkbox, then my SelectUnselect() method completely ignores it. Even though I can see both of them when I debug.

Essentially after manually clicking on any of the checkboxes, it gets completely ignored when I click SelectAll to check or uncheck.

Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Please add all relevant code to the question so we can see a working example of the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - see sample code. You can try to click on SelectAll first, to be sure it works. However once you manually click on any of the 2 checkboxes (not select all) then you will notice the method will completely ignore it.

Comment: @connexo - well that was easy. If you want to post as answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `checked` serves **only as the initial value**.

Manipulating the **attribute** later has **no effect on the checkbox**; use the **property `checked`** instead. This works the same way as the `value` attribute on text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve it.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="selectAll" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="other-checkboxes" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="other-checkboxes"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".selectAll").on("change", function(){
    if ($(this).prop("checked")){
        // selectAll is checked
        $(".other-checkboxes").prop("checked", true);
    }
    else{
        // selectAll is not checked
        $(".other-checkboxes").prop("checked", false);
    }
});

$(".other-checkboxes").on("change", function(){

    // checking if all the "other-checkboxes" checkboxes are checked
    if ($('.other-checkboxes:checked').length == $('.other-checkboxes').length){
        $(".selectAll").prop("checked", true);
    }
    else{
        $(".selectAll").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```